# Selenium Webdriver click() not doing anything

Tags: java, selenium, click, webdriver

Should be simple enough, I have the following code: -

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents",false);

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);

// And now use it
driver.get("dvfow01.mySite.com");
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create")).click();
System.out.println("test");
driver.findElement(By.id("CreateDeal")).click();
```

It clicks the first item (linkText of "Create") but never gets to the next line in the sequence.  The moment I close the browser it hits the next line, printing out the text "test" and then obviously immediately crashes due to no element on closed window.

Any suggestions? I'm running all the latest versions...

The clicking of this link expands a hidden section via tagit.js so it looks like a drop down but isn't...  the html of the page looks like so...

```
  <li class="dropdown"><a href='#' class='collermenu dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Create <b class='caret'></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a id="createDeal">Deal</a></li>
            <li><a id="second">someting</a></li>
            <li><a id="third">something else</a></li>
            <li><a id="fourth">a fourth</a></li>
            <li><a id="fifth">the last</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I've spoken with my devs and they tell me that they are running something called signalr with foreverframe to continually comminucate back to the server for updates/popups etc?

Anyone heard of this or used it in conjunction with selenium?

Comment: why are you attempting to use a hub as opposed to just a simple local server?  Instead of using `new RemoteWebDriver()` use `new IEDriver()`

Comment: Furthermore, you should use `DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();`.  Line 2 of your code literally does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I could come up with for this was to change the method by which the devs utilised signalR in our dev environment.  They were using foreverframe but this just doesn't play ball with selenium, so instead I had to get them to change back to long polling.  Not ideal to have different configurations in dev vs live but it gets round the issue...

Answer (score 3):

> It clicks the first item (linkText of "Create") but never gets to the next line in the sequence.

That usually stems from an application issue.  WebDriver will wait until the page is fully loaded, and my guess is that it never does fully load.  there is an app issue, which would explain why after you close it, it echo's that.

I'm willing to bet too, that if you waited long enough, Selenium would spit an exception.

A suggestion i'd make, is to clean up your code first off..

Don't use a Hub unless you expect it to be a dedicated server. If you are running tests on your local machine, just use a local webdriver instance.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents",false);

WebDriver driver = new IEDriver(capabilities);

driver.get("http://myurl.com");
```

Second, take out, *and LEAVE out* all explicit waits like `Thread.sleep()`.  Selenium has what's called Implicit waits.  If these aren't enough, write your own method like `waitForElement(By)` which will wait for something to appear.

Also, it might help to explain what happens after clicking that `<a href="someurl">Create</a>`

#### Edit

After your edits, i can give you some more pointers.  If your scenario is..

> 1. Click the link.
> 2. Click an item in the dropdown.

Then you can do something like -

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.dropdown > a[data-toggle='dropdown']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.dropdown li > a#createDeal")).click();
```

As I am not fond of doing these manual findElements, i'd like to share with you a great project to help you get started with Selenium WebDriver Java.  [Getting started with selenium (java) on GitHub](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium)

It is a pretty functional project that includes a fluent style interface, and abstracts you away from all these `driver.findElement()`'s.  Your test would look something like,

```
@Config(url="http://mysite.com", browser=Browsers.IE)
public class MyTest extends AutomationTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // we will be at mysite.com right now.
        click(By.cssSelector("li.dropdown > a[data-toggle='dropdown']")
        .click(By.cssSelector("li.dropdown li > a#createDeal"))
        .validatePresent(By.id("someIdThatAppearsAFterClicking"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, any ideas how I can tell if anything on the page is still running to cause it to lock up?  Once the create link is clicked it just makes a dropdown appear, have added the html above.

Comment: This is a reasonably good answer, but I cannot in good conscience upvote any answer that encourages the use of implicit waits. Using them obscures the code's actions for dubious benefit. If code readability is the reason for avoiding use of `WebDriverWait`, one should use a wrapper framework that hides that implementation detail, as you suggest for other reasons.

Comment: that's what this framework is - a wrapper framework which abstracts the person from ever implicitly waiting.  it all depends on philosophical bend too.  It all comes down to, "does it work".  This - does.

Comment: I tried the manual find elements using css but that did the same thing, clicked the first and never proceeded past.  I've spoken with my devs and they tell me that they are running something called signalr with foreverframe to continually comminucate back to the server for updates/popups etc?  Anyone heard of this or used it in conjunction with selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('ID').style.display='block';");
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ID")));
select.selectByVisibleText("value");
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

By using java script executor and make the element visible then click on the element through ID. Hope it hepls..